# How to use ES2022 modules in an extension?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

To test various module types in my extension code, I changed my tsconfig.json file so:

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "declaration": true,
        "module": "ES2022",
        "target": "ES2022",
        "outDir": "out",
        "removeComments": true,
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "inlineSources": true,
        "isolatedModules": false,
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "allowUmdGlobalAccess": true, // For D3.js
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "strictNullChecks": true,
        "alwaysStrict": true
    },
    "compileOnSave": true,
    "include": [
        "src/*.ts",
        "src/backend/**/*.ts",
        "src/frontend/**/*.ts",
        "src/parser/**/*.ts",
        "src/webview-scripts/**/*.ts",
        "test/**/*.ts"
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        ".vscode-test",
        "images",
    ]
}
```

and everything transpiles fine. However, the extension doesn't load in the vscode development host saying:

> Activating extension 'mike-lischke.vscode-antlr4' failed: Cannot use import statement outside a module.

something which works properly when using `CommonJS` as module type. What must be changed to support the ES2022 module type in my extension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Node.js only works with the CommonJS module type (the one it invented when there were no modules yet). No other module type works currently in Node.js (which is what is used in VS Code), at the time of writing this.

However, you can still target ES2022, for latest language features.